# Performance Testing for Solace Systems

Tags: oracleforms, solace-mq

Could you please share an approach or any strategy to do performance testing for Solace middle-ware systems and Oracle forms

Answer (score 0):

Solace provides a testing tool called SDKPerf that is easy to use to quickly measure the performance of a Solace router. It is designed to be an extensible testing platform and it is available for many different Solace APIs.

SDKPerf is a very capable tool and can be used for most performance scenarios, depending on what you are looking for.

It is available here, along with documentation:
http://dev.solace.com/tech/sdkperf/